# How do I disable suphp on ubuntu 10.04 server

Tags: php, apache2, webserver, ubuntu-10.04, suphp

I have put together a small ubuntu 10.04 server with apache2 and php for use only for testing purposes. I am finding suphp keeps getting in my way. Doubtless this is a useful tool for security etc, but right now, as this is only a local testing ground I would like to disable it to prevent it continually throwing errors relating to file ownership etc.

So, as the title says:  How  do I disable suphp on ubuntu server 10.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a2dismod suphp -> to disable su php mod

Comment: Please consider to explain this answer in more details.

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for! I am configuring VirtualHost for my development environment's vagrant box. I won't recommend this in production tho.

Answer (score 0):

instead of disabling all use virtual hosts conf file or http.conf and add

```
 <VirtualHost ..>
  suPHP_Engine off
  ...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Only one problem though.  When I put it in my virtual hosts file as suggested I get this error: "Invalid command 'suPHP_Engine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration". All I get from google about this error is the suggestion that suphp is not installed, but my suphp error messages beg to differ.

Comment: I do not know if suphp installed or not. You can try this: aptitude install libapache2-mod-suphp

Comment: suphp is definitely installed response to apt-get is "libapache2-mod-suphp is already the newest version"

Comment: apt-get differs from aptitude in some aspects.  I suggest you first update ubuntu and then try aptitude. Let me know the result.

Comment: sorry to be so slow coming back.  I did as you suggested and updated ubuntu and tried aptitude.  It still tells me libapache2-mod-sus is installed